# Embedding GOOGLE COLABS as an IFRAME

Tags: google-colaboratory

We are trying to use Google Colabs for an online programming course. We would like to pull the various files into the appropriate parts of the courseware using an iFrame. Unlike Sheets, docs, and slides, there is no publish to Web option in Colab. Is this forthcoming?

Comment: I would also very much like to know this as well.

Comment: Me too.. Will have a look at it now

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208821/how-to-embed-a-live-colab-notebook-in-a-website

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Embed a LIVE Colab Notebook in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208821/how-to-embed-a-live-colab-notebook-in-a-website)