# How to Embed a LIVE Colab Notebook in a website?

Tags: apache-spark, web, deployment, data-science, embed

I want to build a website and deploy it to github pages or heroku. My question is: is it possible to embed a LIVE (where I can run code) Google Colab notebook in the website i'll be hosting?

I want this embeded colab notebook to execute spark code!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Even if the answer is a bit late, I came across the same problem and to the conclusion that this is at the moment still not possible.

There was, however, a feature request opened a while ago [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1225). I think the most you can do is to upvote the issue.

#### Embed without executing

There is a half-functioning workaround though...

You **can** export your already executed notebook as a gist and embed this into your webpage.

1. Save Colab as a Gist (Colab -> File -> Save a copy as Github Gist)
2. Make the Gist public (Gist -> Edit -> Make public)
3. Embed the link into your webpage

For further instructions, details and screenshots see [this article](https://medium.com/@lzhou1110/how-to-embed-google-colaboratory-into-medium-in-3-steps-487b525b103c).