# How to Embed(Inframe) Google Colab in Blog or Webpages

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am curretnly trying to use Google Colabs for data science project. We would like to pull the various files into the appropriate parts of the my personal website using an iFrame. Unlike Sheets, docs, and slides, there is no publish to Web option in Colab. Is there anyone got any expereience before?

Comment: I think you may found this other thread useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208821/how-to-embed-a-live-colab-notebook-in-a-website

Comment: Ya , this help a lot, but this one you need to save to github gist, is there any way you can directly use it from github repository

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Embed a LIVE Colab Notebook in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208821/how-to-embed-a-live-colab-notebook-in-a-website)